# MVC Php resources

Tags: php, frameworks

I wanted to learn php. And I'm a beginner when it comes to web programming. So, I'm planning to start out without using any frameworks until i get reasonably accustomed to the language fundamentals [ I have got this suggestion from other posts in SO ]. Also, I found couple of posts in SO to learn php by following the documentation in php.net their official site.

But, I have seen couple of posts which suggested developers to refer to the sites/books that stressed on mvc along with php. So, am I going in the right direction of choosing php.net for starting on php?

[ Please dont close this question as "incompletely consturcted" as I had hard time constructing it and also I am planning to start from tomorrow so this response would be very important:) ].

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any book about this, but you can try following [articles](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+mvc).

Comment: view source code for an MVC framework and try to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @dqhendricks, that might be a little too much for a beginner who doesn't even know the language very well...

Comment: @Radu is still good to realize that the option is there. maybe some day.

Comment: Ok..it seems php + mvc might be something which i need to work on after learning php. In this case could you just suggest some websites which do not use any frameworks and teach php. The reason why I'm more oriented towards learning php without a framework is that I have come across many posts that indicated that core knowledge might be missed. So, request you guys to share some good resources that could pitch in here.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z7vXAI0z5I8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When some one ask me, how to learn PHP, then I ask him to start from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) as this site contain tuturials to do something. Then I recommend you to get some good PHP books/ebooks. [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/) video lectures is also good place to start if those are affordable for you. Otherwise try ebooks of wrox,packt and sams is good place to learn PHP. As intention of writers is to teach you PHP so they tell you so many things while php.net like sites are good for people who already know how to work but just use it for reference purpose.

Once you have good or atleast basic knowledge of PHP then you should learn some MVC framwork like Code Igniter or Yii e.t.c.

However, currently there are so much developers in PHP and they have so much in them like they know many frameworks, they know many CMS so I think it is wise to enter in some more specific framework sort of thing like RubyOnRails, like Django e.t.c. But still it is just a thought, if you really like PHP and want to learn it then I hope that above will give you a good idea of how to learn.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

language is always a matter of preference and my preference would be asp.net mvc3 (soon 4) far more than php.  If you learn php you can develop php.  If you learn C# with asp.net you can use that for countless platforms (iPhone apps with monotouch, android with monodroid, windows phone apps, desktop apps, cross platform apps with mono, extremely nice 3d games with unity, and the options keep going).

also an argument for php is the large group of free contributors since its open source, my opinion is microsoft makes their tools amazing cause its one of their large livelyhoods.  I have never seen an ide that can come close to visual studio 2010, not even ballpark (and the free versions are very nice too).

finally there are tons of free videos posted all the time.  Reading is nice but this is 2012 not 1992... i had to read to learn, you dont.  Invest in a cheap 2nd monitor and watch demos on one monitor doing it on the second.  With asp.net and www.asp.net you will be developing amazing apps extremely quickly and learning a language u can achieve mostly everything you would want to in todays industry, all for free.

hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

php.net is a reference site, not really a place to learn PHP. MVC is something different, it's not PHP specific, and anyway there are different flavours of it.

I would just get one of the APress or Wrox books and go through it.

Comment: So, could you please point me to any links where MVC is followed in conjunction with php without any framework...

Comment: No, first because I don't know any, and second because I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/ is only a reference for the language PHP, Model-View-Controller is something different.

If you are searching for a MVC-framework, I would recommend CodeIgniter.

Comment: He explicitly states that he doesn't want to use a framework.